# Quill adds unwanted <br> to lists in when using vue-quill-editor

Tags: html, vue.js, quill

I'm relying on `vue-quill-editor` to allow users to creat notes in my application.  The first time a user creates a list, it is saved as intended.

For example, the HTML saved may look like:

```
<div> Test: </div>
   <ol>
     <li> One </li>
     <li> Two </li>
   </ol>
```

When a user edits the note however, the content is rendered with a 
 tag before the list begins.

```
<div> Test: </div>
<br>
   <ol>
     <li> One </li>
     <li> Two </li>
   </ol>
```

If the user doesn't remove this tag it gets saved.  A new 
 tag is added every time the user edits the note.  Because I'm using vue-quill-editor, I'm not sure if I can use something like dangerouslyPasteHTML to fix this issue.  Is there any configuration I could try to alleviate the problem? Or could I wrap the content in some tags that may help?

Answer (score 3):

This issue can be solved using the `matchVisual: false` configuration for the quill clipboard module.  This approach is mentioned in a number of discussions on the Quill issues board, but the [documentation](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#matchvisual) on the config is not very clear.

My clipboard options look like

```
options : {
  modules: {
    toolbar: '#toolbar',
    clipboard: {
        matchVisual: false
    }
  }
}
```

This fixes the issue and no < br > tags are added.

Answer (score 0):

After heading hours to find a solution for this, I found one way to remove 
 tags.

I have used the javascript function to remove the tags

```
filteredHTML = editorContent.replace('<br>','')
```

to remove all the 
 from the editors output use this

```
filteredHTML = editorContent.replace(/<br>/g,'')
```